# Filter OUT Xcode Console Output (Return NOT text)

Tags: ios, xcode, swiftui

I seem to be forever searching for items in my console output in Xcode because the application is Core Data and CloudKit - which generates LOTS of console messages making scanning impossible. I would like to be able to say "give me all output  Except anything that contains CoreData: CloudKit" but I have not been able to do this.

[image]

I may be imagining things but it seems like a couple of years ago there was a NOT filter in the console filter window.

Any Guidance would be appreciated. Xcode 13.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add some arguments

Project (Next to Play Button) > Edit Scheme > Run > Arguments > Arguments Passed On Launch

Add

```
-com.apple.CoreData.Logging.stderr 0
-com.apple.CoreData.CloudKitDebug 0
-com.apple.CoreData.ConcurrencyDebug 0
-com.apple.CoreData.MigrationDebug 0
-com.apple.CoreData.SQLDebug 0
```

This will minimize the messages to errors. The zeros can be changed to numbers 0-4. 4 giving you the most detailed messages